# UICollectionView horizontal columns with vertical scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to get a UICollectionView to display horizontal columns when on iPad.

This is my current layout when on iPhone (Collection view scrolls vertically):

[image]

Each UICollectionViewCell has a dynamic height depending on the content but the width is set to 100% of the screen width.

The cell height is set like this:

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout 
           as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

     flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)     

 }
```

It's a standard UICollectionView using the usual dataSource/delegate methods (sizeForItemAtIndexPath, cellForItemAtIndexPath etc.)

When on iPad, I'm adjusting the width depending on the number of columns required:

```
var numberOfColumns = 1

if screenWidth > 760 {
     numberOfColumns = 2
}

let cellWidth = screenWidth/numberOfColumns
```

Adjusting the width of the columns gives me this:

[image]

But i'm trying to get something like this:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this using UICollectionView?

A few notes about the collection view:

- Layout is set to Flow
- Scroll direction is vertical
- Headers are a fixed height
- Cell height is dynamic based on content
- I need the collection view to scroll vertically if the content extends outside of the screen